# How to push data from Spring Boot to Elastic using Elasticsearch Java API Client?

Tags: elasticsearch

newbie here!

I see a lot of examples to push data from Java service to Elastic with Java high level REST client,
but now that it's deprecated - How do I use Elasticsearch Java API Client to push data?

Here I can see only example of creating index and searching for data:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.17/api-conventions.html

If you can point me in the right direction or a github repo, that would mean a lot!

Thank you!

Comment: please check below my answer and marked as solution if it really helps you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not find any specific example. But here is [test class](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/blob/7.17/java-client/src/test/java/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/end_to_end/RequestTest.java) which have [Data Ingestion](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/blob/2c9c055f2e9a421a0979717161f4493a23d4bcb1/java-client/src/test/java/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/end_to_end/RequestTest.java#L107) and [Bulk Ingestion](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/blob/2c9c055f2e9a421a0979717161f4493a23d4bcb1/java-client/src/test/java/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/end_to_end/RequestTest.java#L210) test method. I hope this will help you to atleast start something.